# How to use regex to locate datetime template?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I have a list of strings and I want to find the location of the date time signature of each string.
the strings look like this:

```
str1 = 'folder1\folder2\some_words_change_01_03__01_10_some_more_words'
```

obviously the numbers also change between strings.

I want to extract the date time from each string.
so far I tried:

```
re.search(r'(\d+_\d+__\d+_\d+)',good_experiments[1]).start()
```

got `NoneType`.

I'm not understanding the regex definitions.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ should get you going

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to have research, design or coding work done for you, nor is it intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this site : https://regexr.com/

Write some dates in the text so you can try and understand how regex works

Try something like `re.search(r'[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}__[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}')`

Comment: by the way you can use \d instead of [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Your `re.search` seems to be working with example string (`str1`) you provided

```
import re
str1 = 'folder1\folder2\some_words_change_01_03__01_10_some_more_words'
print(re.search(r'(\d+_\d+__\d+_\d+)',str1).start())
```

output

```
33
```

Are you sure `good_experiments[1]` holds content of `str1`? Please do `print(good_experiments[1])` immediately before `re.search` and write its output.

Comment: Using `\d+` here seems kind of unspecific. Numbers that represent date/time allow for a more precise `regex`, which would make it more selective and thus more reliable.